# Classic ASP Recordset and SQL Server 2008 - DateTime formatting problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, recordset

I am working with a Classic ASP file upload application which uses the Recordset.AddNew functionality to insert to a database.
There is a form that submits data to this application, and the application (using Recordset) gets the form variables, like below:

`Set RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.AddNew
RS("A_Category")=Form("strA_Category")
RS("SP_VersionYear")=Form("strSP_VersionYear")`

The Form("strSP_VersionYear") is a hidden variable that holds a string variable, set in the form page as:

`strSP_VersionYear="2014"`

When this variable is inserted into the database, it is into a column of DateTime data type.  Inserting the year only, in a string just like the above, has worked with a SQL statement (in an Insert statement), but, for some reason, it throws an error (below) when trying to insert via a Recordset (as illustrated above).

`Provider error '80020005'
Type mismatch`

Is there a way that this can be formatted to successfully insert into a DateTime column?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what month and day do you want for the year?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either change the datatype of your SQL column, or append a prefix to the version year when you submit.  Ie. `"01-01-" &YEAR & " 12:00:00"`

You can also convert the input element in SQL server within the SQL statement itself, if you can get in there.  It would be `Convert(datetime,'2014')` and it will do all the prefixing for you.